# MongoDb synchronization issues

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using mongoose to register users for testing purposes.

In my registration system, the server send a notification request to another server each time the number of registered users reach 10.

code example

```
if(myApp.users.length === 10){
  axios.post('/message')
}
```

To register a new user i use `.save()`

My app was hosted on Heroku during several weeks and everything was working fine.

However, I've decided to migrate to AWS Lambda and now it seems I have  synchronization issues with Mongoose/Mongodb : My app doesn't always send the notification request when the number of registered users reach 10. Let's say it only works 60% of the time whereas it was 100% while I was using heroku. I think this is related with the serverless architecture of AWS Lamba but I have no idea how I can fix that.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: How are you storing/accessing `myApp.users`?

Comment: `users` is an array of object e.g. `[{name:"John"},{name:"Jack}] ` so to add a user I just push a new object to the existing array.

Comment: lambda's aren't long running processes. To guarantee persistence of the list of users between requests, it needs to be written somewhere like mongodb

Comment: or just queried from mongodb